# In which situation should we consider a dataset as imbalanced?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, random-forest, class-imbalance

I'm facing a problem about making a classification on a dataset. The target variable is binary (with 2 classes, 0 and 1). I have 8,161 samples in the training dataset. And for each class, I have:

- class 0: 6,008 samples, 73.6% of total numbers.
- class 1: 2,153 samples, 26.4%

My questions are:

- In this case, should I consider the dataset I used as an imbalanced dataset?
- If it was, should I process the data before using RandomForest to make a prediction?
- If it was not an imbalanced dataset, could somebody tell me in which situation (like what ratio for each class) I could consider a dataset as imbalanced?

Comment: As a heads up, class imbalance almost certainly is not a problem. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he
https://www.fharrell.com/post/class-damage/
https://www.fharrell.com/post/classification/ 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/359936/247274 
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464636/proper-scoring-rule-when-there-is-a-decision-to-make-e-g-spam-vs-ham-email
https://twitter.com/f2harrell/status/1062424969366462473?lang=en

Comment: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/114111/82468

Answer (score 1):

Intuitively, it seems like an imbalanced dataset to have ~75/25 ratio of class labels.

If you want to take a look at it theoretically, you can do a hypothesis test. For a sample size of 8161, you can assume that the dataset is 50/50 as null hypothesis and then compute the probability that a number extreme as 6008 or more of them belong to one class as p-value and then try to reject the null hypothesis if the p value is low (less than 0.05 or 0.01 as per choice.)

This can be done using a binomial distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can speak of imbalanced targets if (in case of a binary classification problem) the classes are not represented in a 50:50 manner. This is almost always the case.

With about 25/75 in your case, I would see this as „imbalanced“. There are some strategies to deal with this problem, such as (re)sampling so that you achieve a 50:50 balanced sample (essentially you will lose observations in the majority class here). Alternatively you can use synthetic oversampling (SMOTE) and related rechniques.

However, some packages come with built-in options to deal with unbalanced targets, e.g. sklearn‘s random forest (option `class_weight`). Check the docs.

Comment: This is bad advice. You should never over sample on unbalanded datasets. Only under-representitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try ydata-profiling (https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling).
There's a property that measure whether a class is imbalanced or not based on entropy, might be helpful.

https://github.com/ydataai/ydata-profiling/blob/master/src/ydata_profiling/model/pandas/imbalance_pandas.py

The concept to validate imbalanced classes is pretty straightforward - on a dataset of n instances, if you have k classes of size Ci you can compute Shanon Entropy as follows:

[image]

It is one of the most precise metrics I've found, to validate whether the dataset is imbalanced, given **Shanon-Entropy** is commonly used to measure the impurity or uncertainty within a set of data.

Comment: Do you mind to point to us specifically which property it is? There are quite a lot of things in this project.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Just updated the details :)